# Assets REST API - target specific BU/MID

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, content-builder, node.js

I have successfully downloaded and pushed an asset using REST API;
I have my installed package enabled for 2 BU's now;

How do I specify a BU/MID in my request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not in your Asset API request that you specify it. When your integration authenticates, it does so on behalf of a user with an MID. If you want to push to a different MID you need to re-auth under the other account. If you need to push to the two at the same time, you will need to maintain two different sessions.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will need to authenticate into the desired Business Unit to generate an access token before processing your request. You'll just need to specify the account_id when making that auth token call.

[Here's a link to the documentation on that.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm)